# In GitHub what exactly is an addition?

Tags: git, github

I've never quite understood exactly what an addition or deletion is in GitHub. Is it a new line added? If yes, are the number of additions you had on a project the number of lines you have written in that project?

Comment: Lines added and removed of a commit are the ones returned by the `diff` command. You should be just aware that modified lines are seen as an addition and a deletion.

Comment: @Philippe Does that mean that every addition counts as a modification when checking total additions on a repo? What is then counted as addition and deletion? Is removing one char from one line a deletion and adding one char to a line an addition?

Comment: A change on a line (the type of change, adding chars or deleting them, doesn't matter) is seen as 1 line added and 1 line deleted. So, no, "removing one char from one line a deletion and adding one char to a line an addition" is false. They are both seen as 1 line added + 1 deleted. Use the command `git diff` to display changes and you will understand. Lines considered added has a '+' sign at the begin of the line and deleted a '-'.

Answer (score 2):

The number of additions (noted by + sign) represents how many lines you have created or edited .